# Why do I get UnboundLocalError in my second code but not in the first?

Tags: python

When I execute

```
x = 0

def f():
    print('x' in locals())
    x = 1
    print('x' in locals())

f()
```

I get what I expect, namely

```
False
True
```

Yet when I execute

```
x = 3

def f():
    print(x, 'x' in locals())
    x = 7
    print(x, 'x' in locals())

f()
```

I expect to get

```
3 False
7 True
```

but instead I get the `UnboundLocalError`.

If Python knows that on the next line there comes an assignment of the label `x` in the local scope (and so the name `x` is already in the local scope but it wasn't assigned yet) then why does it let me inquire about `x` in my first code?

**Added**:

Why does it raise the error even though `x = 7` comes after the first `print(x, 'x' in locals())`?

Comment: Just FYI here, but don't use `locals()` in actual code. Or `globals()`. Or `eval()`. Or `exec()`.

Comment: The first searches for the character `"x"` in `locals()`.  The second function tries to use the variable `x` and then assign to it.  If you want to use the global version, specify `global x`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/python-variable-scope-error

Comment: @TigerhawkT3: thanks. I'm just using it while trying to learn.

Comment: @cdarke: and why does it raise the error even though `x = 7` comes after the first `print(x, 'x' in locals())`?

Comment: Because there is a compile phase and a run-phase.  Python is not interpreted in the same way as a shell script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dis.dis` for first function:

```
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('x')
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (locals)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            0
              9 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
             12 PRINT_ITEM
             13 PRINT_NEWLINE

  3          14 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             17 STORE_FAST               0 (x)

  4          20 LOAD_CONST               1 ('x')
             23 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (locals)
             26 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             29 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
             32 PRINT_ITEM
             33 PRINT_NEWLINE
             34 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             37 RETURN_VALUE
```

`dis.dis` for second function:

```
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 ('x')
              6 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (locals)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             12 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
             15 BUILD_TUPLE              2
             18 PRINT_ITEM
             19 PRINT_NEWLINE

  3          20 LOAD_CONST               2 (7)
             23 STORE_FAST               0 (x)

  4          26 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)
             29 LOAD_CONST               1 ('x')
             32 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (locals)
             35 CALL_FUNCTION            0
             38 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
             41 BUILD_TUPLE              2
             44 PRINT_ITEM
             45 PRINT_NEWLINE
             46 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             49 RETURN_VALUE
```

Critical difference is line: `4          26 LOAD_FAST                0 (x)`.

Basically, there is a assignment statement to name `x` in current scope, and therefore `x` is resolved as a local name. Resolving is performed in compilation phase. Compiled bytecode uses [`LOAD_FAST`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-LOAD_FAST) and not [`LOAD_GLOBAL`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#opcode-LOAD_GLOBAL).

Compilation to bytecode and execution are [two independent steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299648/python-compilation-interpretation-process) - language is not actually interpreted line-by-line.

Answer (score 0):

The error is from printing `x`, not from the call `'x' in locals()`. You are not actually doing anything with the variable `x` when you do `'x' in locals()` since you are giving it a string value, not a reference to a variable.