# When a statement returns boolean value, how to use that value in an if statement

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

I am a new learner in programming, and I was trying to check whether a word exists in a file. I put the words into a dictionary (the exercise told me to put it in a *dict* as a key and ignore the value), and then let the user input a word, then I tried to check whether it is in the dictionary.

```py
words_dict = dict()

fhand = open('desktop/codingMaterial/words.txt')
for line in fhand:
    line = line.rstrip()
    t = line.split()
    for word in t:
        words_dict[word] = 0

# check if word exists
v = input('Enter a variable: ')
if v in words_dict == True:
    print('Exist.')
else:
    print('Does not exist.')
```

I tried to run this, but no matter which word I input, the output was always *'Does not exist.'*. I think I did something wrong in the if statement, but I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: 1) print the dictionary before you check it 2) try `if (v in words_dict) == True:`

Comment: Also, use a set for checking existence, not a dict

Comment: ``if (v in words_dict) == True: `` or ``if v in words_dict:``

Comment: @cricket_007, why do you give a recommendation without reading question?

Comment: @Olvin because teachers/exercises often are wrong

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank you for your suggestion. That is a exercise in the Dictionary chapter, I think that's the reason the exercise told me to do so. Anyway thanks so much :)

Comment: @Todd I tried to use a word in that file and the result is 'Does not exists.'

Comment: @Todd Yeah I have added it. And the words_dict has exactly what I want in it

Comment: @cricket_007, the idea of exercise is to follow it's subject. And, btw, being self-confident is good, but better to avoid blaming other people without knowing context.

Comment: @MayDing also print the text you got from user input so you can verify that too visually: `print("%s exists." % v)` and `print("%s doesn't exist." % v)`

Comment: @Todd Thank you for  your suggestion, I thinks it's really helpful

Comment: Looks like @cricket_007 is a little unpopular on this thread, but I do understand his suggestion to use a `set`. And I do think it's a good suggestion @MayDing. With a `set` you don't get duplicate strings in your test data. However, this is a school assignment for `dict` objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if v in word_dict == True` is evluated as `if v in word_dict and word_dict==True`. This is called operator chaining.

Check this byte-code using [dis module.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#dis.dis)

```
import dis
a={'a':1,'b':2,'c':3}

In [53]: dis.dis('"a" in a == True')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('a')
              2 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              4 DUP_TOP
              6 ROT_THREE
              8 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
             10 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    18
             12 LOAD_CONST               1 (True)
             14 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
             16 RETURN_VALUE
        >>   18 ROT_TWO
             20 POP_TOP
             22 RETURN_VALUE
In [54]: dis.dis('"a" in a and a==True')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('a')
              2 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
              4 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
              6 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    14
              8 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
             10 LOAD_CONST               1 (True)
             12 COMPARE_OP               2 (==)
        >>   14 RETURN_VALUE
```

Both are evaluated in the same way. And in your case `word_dict==True` is always `False` as `word_dict` is a *dictionary*. So, it would never enter the `if` block and `else` block is executed.

`if some_bool_expr == True` and can be written as `if some_bool_expr` and `if some_bool_expr==False` can be written as `if not some_bool_expr`.

[*Byte-code Instructions documentation link*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html#python-bytecode-instructions)

`LOAD_CONST` and `LOAD_NAME`: push value onto the stack. After line 2 *top of the stack* is `a`(not `'a'`)

`DUP_TOP`: Duplicates the reference on top of the stack and pushes onto the stack. Now *top of the stack* is `a`.

`ROT_THREE`: Lifts second and third stack item one position up moves top down to position three. Now `TOS`(top of the stack) is third element (`a`) and 2nd element (`a`) is now `TOS`, 3rd element `'a'` is now 2nd element.

`COMPARE_OP`: Tells the interpreter to pop the two topmost stack elements and perform an membership test(`in`) between them, pushing the Boolean result back onto the stack. `'a' in a` is done and result is pushed onto the stack i.e `True`. Now stack has TOS as `True` and duplicate reference from `DUP_TOP` below it.

`JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP`: If TOS is false, sets the bytecode counter to target and leaves TOS on the stack. Otherwise (TOS is true), TOS is popped. In our example, `TOS` is `True` so. `TOS` is popped. Now `TOS` is `a`.

`LOAD_CONST` `True` is pushed onto the stack. `COMPARE_OP` `==`. `True==a` is done which `False`. Now `TOS` is `False`.

`RETURN_VALUE`: Returns with TOS to the caller of the function. In our example, `TOS` is `False` at this point. `False` is returned.

`POP_TOP`: Removes the top-of-stack (TOS) item.

The only difference between both the expressions is that `a` is evaluate twice in the 2nd one.

Also refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3299724/12416453

Comment: I wouldn't say "same way", as `dis` does show differences and because `a` is evaluated *twice* in the long version (which in general can make a difference, as `a` could've changed between the two evaluations).

Comment: This is a good demo. How exactly do you get this output? Nevermind, I figured it out.

Comment: This is a good demo for experienced Pythoners. Maybe a little explanation on the effect of dup and rot would help.

Comment: @Todd Yeah, I should've at least left a link to `dis` module documentation.

Comment: @Ch3steR, you have, "perform an inequality comparison" in your explanation. I think you meant an "'in' membership test operation".

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. Though I can not completely understand the byte-code part cause I'm a beginner, your answer solves my question. I'll investigate on that part later. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 3):

A test of how `x in y == z` gets evaluated, by using wrappers that print what's going on:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def __eq__(self, other):
        print(self, '==', other)
        return True
    def __contains__(self, value):
        print(value, 'in', self)
        return True
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.value)

C(1) in C(2) == C(3)
```

Prints `1 in 2` followed by `2 == 3`, [as it should](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons).

Not `1 in 2` followed by `True == 3`.

Not `2 == 3` followed by `1 in True`.

Comment: Nice example to show operator chaining. Heap can you tell the differences in the examples I provided. Python docs says *expr1 opr1 expr2 opr2 expr3* is evaluated as *expr1 opr1 expr2 and expr2 opr2 expr3* right?

Comment: @Ch3steR In your particular example, the chain version and the `and` version have the same meaning, they're just executed a bit differently and probably have a speed difference so small it's hard to measure. In general, they *don't* mean the same thing. You're only showing the first half of the documentation's sentence. The second half is "except that [expr2] is evaluated only once". A typical counter-example is when `expr2` is an expression resulting in a different value when it's evaluated a second time. If it's just a variable, I need to get dirty: https://repl.it/repls/UnusualWhoppingMap

Comment: Yes, got your point. And I went through the docs. And `dis` documentation made it clear. Nice example btw ;)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the == True.
It should be just .

```
if v in words_dict:
    print('Exist.')
```

Answer (score 1):

change `if v in words_dict == True:` with `if v in words_dict:`

your issue is related to  [Chaining comparison operators](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/chaining-comparison-operators-python/), both operators `in` and `==` have the same [precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) and are evaluated left-to-right, an equivalent to your code is (already pointed by @Ch3steR):

```
if v in word_dict and word_dict==True
```

Comment: It's the same thing, no?

Comment: @cricket_007, no.

Comment: @cricket_007 ``if v in words_dict:`` maybe == ``if (v in words_dict) == True:``

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. So in python the '==' has a higher priority than the 'in'? Am I right?

Comment: what if I want to use the 'False' value? ```if v not in words_dict: ``` Is this a right statement? I run this and it worked, but I'd like to confirm this with you. Thank you

Comment: *" first will evaluate words_dict == True"*... uh... no.

Comment: @MayDing No, they have the *same* precedence, and `in` is evaluated *first* because it's the left one.

Comment: @kederrac `if v in word_dict== True` is evaluated as `if v in word_dict and word_dict == True`.  Like heap mentioned they have same precedence actually.

Comment: Test what? That the `==` is evaluated first? You didn't test that. How do you think you tested it?

Comment: @kederrac How did you test it btw?

Comment: @MayDing Here's a proper test: https://repl.it/repls/TotalJauntySoftwareengineer

Comment: My bad, I was evaluating `1 in {1:1} == True`  as a test

Answer (score 1):

Verifying that the Python interpreter evaluates the subexpression `words_dict == True` first. And not `v in words_dict` (**wrong assumption has been made**). I see from other posts that this statement is not accurate about what the interpreter actually does. Which is pretty interesting. From other descriptions here, it appears the interp regards the `in` operator as being at the same level of precedence as `==`. In either case, you could group the first expression to force the order of evaluation.

```
>>> words_dict == True
False
>>> 'hand' in words_dict == True
False
>>> 'hand' in words_dict
True
>>> ('hand' in words_dict) == True
True
```

If this were an example of production code, one could implement this logic as `(a in b) == c` if that was the intent of the expression. Or if the expression were truly intended to be `a in b == c` as discussed, then it could be implemented explicitly as `(a in b) and (b == c)`.

In many coding style specifications I've seen, there's a requirement that developers use parenthesis to group their subexpressions in boolean expressions. Whether or not the author believes he has a solid grasp of order-of-precedence (without parenthesis), other developers appreciate the diligence and no-assumptions approach of using parenthesis, not only as a safeguard to ensure there aren't any incorrect assumptions, but to show the other developers the intended order of precedence with no ambiguity. This is a good case-in-point.

There are tables showing the order of precedence of operators online that list `in` below `==`. However, this one is directly from docs.python.org and accurately shows that `in` and `==` are at the same level: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence

Comment: See the comments under kederrac's answer.

Comment: Not sure why you mention points. What I mean is that your demo is wrong.

Comment: Well.. the demo's not "wrong", the commands and their results are accurately displayed. But the assumption that `==` takes precedence over `in` was wrong. From other examples, it looks as if they are at the same order of precedence.

Comment: How would you use parenthesis in `a in b == c` *without* changing the meaning?

Comment: I **was** trying to change the meaning ;-) Adding parenthesis ensures that the logic is evaluated in the order I **intend**.

Comment: In this case we want to change it, yes. But I mean your paragraph about coding style in general, when I don't want to change the meaning.

Comment: Oh. got it! I'd do it this way: `(a in b) and (b == c)`. I've updated it @StefanPochmann