# Conditional shadowing of a global variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope, global-variables

```py
VAR = 123

def func(param=False):
    if param:
        VAR = 456
    return VAR

func(True)  # 456
func()      # UnboundLocalError: ...
```

*NB: I do not need to change the global variable!*

I expect that for the first call the function returns a local variable shadowing the global – that actually works. And for for the second call I expect the function to return the global variable – that leads to exception.

Help me please to understand. Why the interpreter doesn't let me conditionally use both global variable **or** local?

I suppose that during the second call the local variable shouldn't be declared and so shouldn't shadow the global variable. Then why it leads to exception?

Comment: you have `VAR = ...` without `global VAR` so it think you want to use all time local variable. You should use `a = VAR` at start and `a = 456` and `return a`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using global variables in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function)

Comment: @furas, I don't want to change the value of global variable, I want to refer to the global variable **or** to the local variable depending on condition

Comment: @Rizquuula, no, because there's nothing about conditions. In the second call the local variable shouldn't be declared and so shouldn't shadow the global variable. Then why it leads to exception?

Comment: The name is always going to be the global.  The only difference with the parameter is that you're CHANGING the global.  Add the `global` statement and it will work fine.  Without that, `VAR` in the function is always considered to be a local.

Comment: @Tim Roberts, no changing, only shadowing

Comment: Do you understand how the interpreter read the code before executing it? There is similar workaround in the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70514761/how-does-python-interpreter-actually-interpret-a-program

Comment: @Rizquuula, yes, but shouldn't the function object be re-compiled depending on condition?

Comment: @Gennadiy -- No.  It's a design choice, and what you're describing is simply not how Python works.  There is a rule.  **IF** you have code in a function that COULD write to a variable, then the variable is considered local to the function throughout the function.  The decision is made at compile time, NOT at runtime.  You need a `global` declaration to override that.  Your expectations are irrelevant -- this is how Python works.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do `conditional shadowing`. You can use only local variable or only global variable.

And when you use `VAR = ...` then it automatically assume that you use local variable.

You have to create other local variable and assign global value or new value.

```
VAR = 123

def func(param=False):
    result = VAR
    if param:
        result = 456
    return result

print(func(True))  # 456
print(func())      # 123
```

And frankly, for me this is more readable and doesn't make confusion if I still use local or global variable.

Answer (score 0):

When you define VAR inside the function python thinks that is the "version" of VAR that you want; in other words, you are defining a local inside the "if" statement, so python references that local variable.

```
def func(param=False):
    if param:
        return VAR
    return VAR
```

**This doesn't cause any issues because you aren't defining the local VAR.** When True is passed in it works because you define the local. But since that local is in the function that's what scope it uses.

```
def func(param=False):
    if param:
        VAR
    return VAR

func()
```

The code above functions fine because you aren't define a local bound variable.

From the comments on here I Read [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70514761/how-does-python-interpreter-actually-interpret-a-program) and it python is put into byte code then run on a virtual machine. So the variable locations needs to be defined before runtime, then during runtime the interpreter knows which way to go.