# Accessing global function's variables in a local function

Tags: python, python-2.7, variables, scope

Here's my test script:

```
def main(): #global
    n = 1
    z = None

    def addone():  #local
        if not z:
            n = n+1
    addone()
    print n

main()
```

I step into the `addone()` function once it hits the calling line.
At this point I can only see the variable `z`, but cannot see `n`.

Now, if `n` is referenced before assignment, shouldn't `z` be too?

Similarly, if I change `n=n+1` to `z='hi'`, I can no longer see `z`!
This is contrary to all my previous beliefs about local/global functions! The more you know, the more you know you don't know about Python.

Question(s):

- Why can I see one but not the other?
- Do I want to be prepending `global` to these variables I want to reassign?

Comment: Perhaps this might be helpful:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/21978980/748858

Comment: ah ha, useful indeed. thanks. I would have thought I had to use `global` outside of the function, but nice that i can use it within.

Comment: wait...maybe it is as I thought. doesn't `global` have to be defined **outside** of the function? I am getting a `NameError: global name 'x' is not defined`. calling it `global` outside of the function as well causes it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is to upgrade to Python 3 and use in the inner function `nonlocal n`.  The second-best, if you absolutely have to stick with Python 2:

```
def main(): #global
    n = [1]
    z = None

    def addone():  #local
        if not z:
            n[0] += 1
    addone()
    print n[0]

main()
```

As usual, "there is no problem in computer science that cannot be solved with an extra level of indirection".  By making `n` a list (and always using and assigning `n[0]`) you are in a sense introducing exactly that life-saving "extra level of indirection".

Comment: Unfortunately I am constrained to python2...this is a very interesting workaround, I may use it for now as I don't think we want to be declaring the variable in question as a `global`.

Comment: @tenwest, yep, `global` should be avoided whenever possible!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after some testing, I realised that it all has to do with the reassignment of variables.

for example:

```
def main(): #global
    n = 1
    z = None

    def addone():  #local
        if not z:
            x = n+1
    addone()
    print n

main()
```

Now shows both `n` and `z` when I am inside the `addone()` function. This is because I am no longer trying to reassign `n`, makes sense to me so as to protect global variables from manipulation if one so happens to use similar names in local functions.